# How to adjust this AS2 to AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

the AS2 code is:

```
MovieClip.prototype.setModel = function(m)
{
    this.model = m;
    this.drawModel(m);
}

MovieClip.prototype.drawModel = drawModel;
```

I tried:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Prototype extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Prototype()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function setModel(m)
        {
            this.model = m;
            this.drawModel(m);
        }

        public function setDrawModel(m)
        {
            this.drawModel = m;
        }

    }
}
```

but there is no "this.model" nither "drawModel(m)" in MovieClip.

Any idea?

Comment: "this.model" and "drawModel(m)" are not part of MovieClip, look for them in other ".as" files from the original source of the code sample you gave us.

Comment: Since you extend MovieClip I think you should call `this.prototype.whatever` instead of `this.whatever`, it's not verified because I can't run an example now but try it.

Comment: @eiefai there was just a single source file

Comment: @dierre there's no prototype in MovieClip

Comment: @dierre by the way, the full source is [this game](http://www.krazydad.com/bestiary/bestiary_asteroids.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have define model and drawModel. I only see setModel and setDrawModel and no variables.

So if you add following inside the class:

private var model:type;

Then your this.model will work.

Comment: But somehing is wrong, becouse this way the model have no use. No other part of the code uses it. But in the AS2 code it exists inside MovieClip and I need set it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Whatever extends MovieClip
 {
    private var _model:DisplayObject;

    public function set model(m:Object):void
    {
       this._model = m;
       this.drawModel();
    }

    private function drawModel():void
    { 
        _model.graphics.beginFill(0); //etc...
    }
 }
```

Then in another class , you can do this

```
 var whatever:Whatever = new Whatever();
 whatever.model = new DisplayObject();
```